# Git Hook запретить мердж коммиты использованные вместо rebase

Tags: git, githooks

Как можно на стороне в репозитории сервера запретить пуши коммитов в которых был использован git merge вместо rebase, когда ветка на которой работаешь ушла в удаленном репозитории далеко и при пуше по умолчанию выполняется merge вместо rebase. Без заставляения разработчиков менять git config rebase.pull true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

насколько я понял, вам всего лишь надо отклонять push-и, содержащие коммиты слияния (если же требуется более сложная логика, смело можете дополнять предложенный ниже скрипт, внося больше элементов искусственного интеллекта).

подойдёт для этого *hook* под названием [`update`](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git#_update):

> Хук update очень похож на pre-receive, за исключением того, что он выполняется для каждой ветки, которую отправитель пытается обновить. Если отправитель пытается отправить изменения в несколько веток, то pre-receive хук будет вызван однократно, а update выполнен для каждой изменяемой ветки. Вместо чтения из stdin, хук принимает три аргумента: название ссылки (ветка), SHA-1 хэш, на который указывала ссылка до отправки, и SHA-1 хэш коммита, отправляемого пользователем. Если скрипт завершается ненулевым кодом, то отклоняются все изменения только для текущей ветки, при этом изменения для других веток всё ещё могут быть применены.

всё что надо — пройтись в цикле по всем полученным коммитам и проверить у каждого коммита количество «родительских» (parent) коммитов: у коммитов слияния их количество будет больше одного. в этом случае завершить работу с ненулевым кодом возврата.

получить список «родительских» коммитов для данного можно с помощью команды `show`:

```
$ git show -s --format=%P 5e23259b959d22281ea8b82ce8546e9436d871e5
2d1dc0c9585dd81a401ed5460f80fcc0a432868a
```

видим один «родительский» коммит — нормально. смотрим и его:

```
$ git show -s --format=%P 2d1dc0c9585dd81a401ed5460f80fcc0a432868a
39bd96ac28597f012ea76076d6207c03f8586d27 7fc12942fd73c4b1c23c8cb95b861cec290c2a12
```

ага! «родителей» больше одного — это коммит слияния. прерываем работу.

подсчитать количество слов в строке можно, например, с помощью программы `wc`, запущенной с опцией `-w`:

```
$ git show -s --format=%P 5e23259b959d22281ea8b82ce8546e9436d871e5 | wc -w
1
$ git show -s --format=%P 2d1dc0c9585dd81a401ed5460f80fcc0a432868a | wc -w
2
```

итого что-нибудь типа такого:

```
#!/bin/sh
branch=$1 # имя указателя (ветка в git — это указатель на коммит)
new=$2    # хэш коммита, на который предлагается переставить указатель
old=$3    # хэш коммита, на который сейчас ссылается указатель

while [ "$new" != "$old" ]; do # пока не добрались до текущего значения
  new=`git show -s --format=%P $new` # получаем родителей коммита
  nparents=`echo $new | wc -w` # считаем их количество
  if [ $nparents -gt 1 ]; then # если оно больше одного
    echo "нельзя пушить коммиты слияния!!11одинодин" >&2
    exit 1 # завершаем скрипт с любым ненулевым кодом возврата
  fi
done
```